# Reforming a difference equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a difference equation, but once I get a certain formula, I do not know how to reform it. There is a solution, but it does not explain how to reform the equation.

[The image of the problem and the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuhxQ.png)

I get to this point $ (\alpha-\beta)*Y_{t+1} = -\beta Y_{t} $, but how do I proceed in order to get the formula from the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a matter of algebraic manipulation:

$$-\frac\beta{\alpha-\beta}=\frac\beta{\beta-\alpha}=\frac{\beta-\alpha+\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}=\frac{\beta-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}+\frac\alpha{\beta-\alpha}=1+\frac\alpha{\beta-\alpha}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you please elaborate it a bit more, how did you get alpha two times and is there a specific formula for this?

Comment: What I did amounts to adding $0$, since $\alpha-\alpha=0$. Doing this does not change the quantity in the numerator, so it's perfectly safe. The idea is to get an expression in the numerator that exactly matches the denominator, which then reduces to $1$.

Comment: Is it necessary to do it this way, because when I did it I got, $ -\beta*Yt / (\alpha - \beta)^{-1} $

Comment: That's totally fine because the expressions are equivalent. My goal was to explain how the author got the expression presented in the screenshot.

Comment: Great, thank you for your help!